# Неправильно парсятся картинки

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

Вообщем имеется код вот такого вида

```
 def parse(url):
    html = get_html(url)
    get_page_data(html)


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r)
    filename = open('525.html','w')
    filename.write(r.text)
    return r.text



def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
    items = soup.find('div',class_='items').find('ul',class_='postload').find_all('li')
    for item in items:
        title = item.find('div',class_='about').find('a',class_='tit').text
        print(title)
        desc =  item.find('div',class_='overdescr').text
        print(desc)
        img = item.find('div',class_='img').find('img')['src']
        print(img)








parse('https://el-dent.ru/selection/?v[12]=205&f=1&s=1')
```

Мне нужно чтобы img имел src нормальной картинки но вместо этого я получаю preloader.gif[image]

Вопрос пишу первый раз так что возможно предоставил не все что нужно

Comment: Это происходит потому что все картинки на сайте вставляются динамически, а до выполнения js все картинки содержат только прелоадер.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_image():
   main_url = "https://el-dent.ru/selection/?v[12]=205&f=1&s=1%27"
   r = requests.get(main_url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
   img_url = soup.find_all('div', class_='img')[0].img['img'] #получаем url картинки первой записи

   return img_url

print(get_image()) #/UserFiles/Image/img6577_36873s.jpg
```